# Android call manager best practice

Tags: android

I wanna make an app that can handle calls (blocking and recording). Before implementing anything, I think about the approach to make this app. My current approach is:

1: MainService- responsible for blocking or recording functionality.

2- BootReceiver- will start MainService when BOOT_COMPLETED.

3- IncomingCallReceiver- start with PHONE_STATE and control MainService according to IDLE, OFFHOOK or RINGING state.

4- OutgoingCallReceiver- starts with OUTGOING_CALL and control MainService to perform blocking or recording operations.

NOTE: instead of using PhoneStateListener, I used STATEs in IncomingCallReceiver. (if PhoneStateListener is necessary than let me know please).

So, can I go ahead with this approach or I must have to implement something new or modify something?